# How to read response or output from a UIWebView in swift 4.0? And how many different ways are there for stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from:)

Tags: swift, xcode, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I'm opening an URL in UIWbView, where user can enter OTP and after submitting it'll provide following response:

**{"success":true,""message":payment success"}**

I want that if the value of **success** is **true**, I'll remove UIWebView from superview.

I don't know how to read the response from UIWebView.

Answer (score 0):

I tried number of strings as parameter in `stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from:)` but finally I figure it out by passing `"document.body.innerHTML"`.

You can use `"document.getElementById('someElement').innerText"`, if you want to read data from HTML elements/components like text fields, etc.

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        print("WebView did finish load...")
        if !webView.isLoading {
            Loader.hideLoading()
        }
        let str = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.body.innerHTML")
        if (str?.contains("\"success\":true"))! {
            print("Success is true")
            self.viewForWebView.removeFromSuperview()
        }else {
            print("Success is false or not found")
        }
    }
```